# Take input before entering main function

Tags: c++, arrays, global-variables

I am trying to declare a 2-dimensional array globally with number of rows and columns left to user to input. I am trying for past hour but couldn't find any way around. Help me.

```
#include<iostream>
using namesapce std;
int m,n,array[m][n];
int main()
{
   cin>>m>>n;
   .
   .
   .
}
```

And somehow i want to reflect the input values of my variables **m** & **n** to my original array.How to do?
And also while implementing the above code it is giving error of "Error Bound Is not an Integer Constant"

Thanks

Comment: You cannot do this. Use any dynamic memory allocation technique instead.

Comment: C and C++ are **different** languages! Do not add the C tag for C++ code.

Comment: For the error message: It exactly tells you what the problem is. Just think about it.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Just because a question displays a lack of understanding doesn't make it a bad question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to allocate a multidimensional array statically the dimensions must be known at compile time.

As your dimensions are not known until runtime you will need to use dynamic memory allocation.

There are a number of ways of dynamically allocating multi-dimensional arrays in C++ and in my opinion none of them are entirely satisfactory. As this is a C++ question I'm going to focus on C++ answers, not C, and use RAII types and standard library containers where possible.

### Boost.Multi-Array

The best option in my opinion is to use [multi_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html) from the boost library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"

int main() {
  int m;
  int n;

  std::cin >> m >> n;

  boost::multi_array<int, 2> array(boost::extents[m][n]);
}
```

boost::multi_array is designed for this purpose and is efficient, powerful and offers the traditional C multi-dimensional array syntax however you do need to use a third-party library.

### Vector of vectors

The easiest way of implementing a dynamic multi-dimensional array in standard C++ is to use a vector of vectors:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> array(m, std::vector<int>(n));
```

This also has the traditional C multi-dimensional array syntax but it might not be very efficient. `std::vector` will do an allocation for each of the inner arrays which might add significant overhead and may give poor data locality.

### Single vector

One option is to not use a multi-dimensional arrays at all and allocate a single contiguous array:

```
std::vector<int> array(m*n);

array[13+n*21] = 7;
```

But you need to convert to a single index to access an element.

### Single vector and an array of pointers

Another option is to allocate one vector to store the data contiguously and then a second vector of pointers to provide the multi-dimensional array syntax.

```
std::vector<int> array_data(n*m);
std::vector<int*> array(n);
for (int i = 0; i != n; ++i)
  array[i] = array_data.data() + m*i;
```

This should be relatively efficient but requires some extra setup. You also lose the benefits of standard library containers on the inner dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's define this global as int** array and then in main function dynamically assign a memory for array.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int** array;

int main()
{
    int xSize;
    int ySize;
    cin >> xSize;
    cin >> ySize;

    int** array = new int*[xSize];
    for(int i = 0; i < xSize; ++i)
    {
        array[i] = new int[ySize];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Another method is to allocate one contiguous block:  `new int [xSize * ySize];`.

Comment: @PatrykZglenicki you can if you create a separate array of pointers to index into your one contiguous block.

Comment: I think it is bad form to provide an answer that includes `new` without `delete`.